# Setting a Timer in Vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I use Vim with ctags to explore the code. I have some key mapping to re-build ctags to be up-to-date. So whenever I don't find a certain tag, I make sure to press Alt+F12 to rebuild the tag, then try again. But I am wondering whether it is possible to automate this task like it is in Visual Studio and other IDEs. I am thinking of making a timer that rebuilds the tags in -say- every 30 minutes. Does anybody know if Vim scripting supports timers?

Also, if you have any suggestion for automating building tags, please share them.

Comment: I made a plugin that automatically generates tags for you in Vim: https://github.com/still-dreaming-1/vim-project-tags It generates the tags automatically when you save a file. There are other plugins out there that do that as well. This one tries to make code definition lookup via tags in Vim feel like a smart code definition lookup in an IDE by using various techniques to avoid false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a timer, it is better to refresh tags every time you actually save your file, that is the moment you have added or removed tags from your code base.

There is some questions addressing this topic already :

[How to automatically update tag file in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1157410/513198)
[How to refresh taglist in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2019665/513198)

Comment: I thought of it, but it makes saving a file a bit annoying, because building the tags takes around 2 seconds.

Comment: @Promather : if you are on windows you can use !start to build the tags in a background process. So you'll be able to keep using vim while file are processed.

Comment: No, I am on Linux, but I do have crantabs in Linux, which executes certain processes regularly. So basically it is the same as Benoit's suggestion above.

Comment: @Promather : in my opinion the issue with using cron is that you're still going to have a delay before being able to use the updated tags. But I don't think there is a perfect solution either for updating tag, and if there is one I'll be glad to know.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought !start is similar to cronjob! So what does it do then? I am just wondering whether it is possible to ask Vim to run a command without having to wait for the response. This way, I can assign an autocmd with every file write to start building the tags without having to wait for the command to finish.

Comment: @Promather : !start allows to start a background process on Windows only sadly. I don't know how to run a process in the background on Linux from Vim. (except by launching the update by an external tool like cron)

Comment: If you refresh only the tag base for the file that has changed, it does not take 2 seconds. That's what I tried to accomplish in lh-tags (see the second link Xavier gave you)

Comment: @Benoit `:execute 'silent! !command &' | redraw!` is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Do it as a scheduled job. Otherwise setup autocmd.

Comment: You mean cronjob? Hmm... yeah, that might be a good idea. How about autocmd? I thought of this, but the only thing I thought of is to make it execute when the file is written, but this will making saving a file slow.

Comment: Yes, but maybe you can set up an autocmd to launch some process in the background?

Comment: Yes, I am just discussing that with @Xaviet actually, but is it possible to make Vim return from command without waiting for the results? If that's possible, then I can simply make an autocmd to run with each file write.

Answer (score 2):

The [Timer routine](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3244) plugin is worth mentioning in that context.