# How to refresh taglist in vim?

Tags: vim

When I make a change to a file, for example, add a function, how can I make the taglist automatically update the "tag list" in its windows after I save the change?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I adapted my setup from the [C++ code completion vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion).

```
map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
```

When needed, I press Ctrl-F12 to regenerate tags.

If you're using [vim-taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/index.html), you could add to your `.vimrc` an [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#:autocmd) for the [BufWritePost](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWritePost) event to update the taglist window after every save:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.cpp :TlistUpdate
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested, but you could try something like:

```
au BufWritePre     *.cpp ks|!ctags %
```

Which basically executes ctags when the buffer for a file ending in `.cpp` gets saved(`:w`).

Answer (score 1):

I did write a [little experimental script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155449/vim-auto-generate-ctags/156781#156781) that automatically and incrementally updates, the "current" tags file on file saving.

(The question is actually redundant with [Vim auto-generate ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155449/vim-auto-generate-ctags) )

Answer (score 1):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Autocmd_to_update_ctags_file

Just add this to your ~/.vimrc

```
function! DelTagOfFile(file)
  let fullpath = a:file
  let cwd = getcwd()
  let tagfilename = cwd . "/tags"
  let f = substitute(fullpath, cwd . "/", "", "")
  let f = escape(f, './')
  let cmd = 'sed -i "/' . f . '/d" "' . tagfilename . '"'
  let resp = system(cmd)
endfunction

function! UpdateTags()
  let f = expand("%:p")
  let cwd = getcwd()
  let tagfilename = cwd . "/tags"
  let cmd = 'ctags -a -f ' . tagfilename . ' --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q ' . '"' . f . '"'
  call DelTagOfFile(f)
  let resp = system(cmd)
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePost *.cpp,*.h,*.c call UpdateTags()
```