# Updating ctags while editing

Tags: vim, refresh, ctags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vim auto-generate ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155449/vim-auto-generate-ctags)

I'm using `ctags` for a while. I noticed that when I create new functions or methods they aren't updated to `ctags` script.

When I want to use

`:ta newFunctioName`

it does not work.

How can I refresh my ctags or set some automatic refreshing?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Auto Tag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1343) is a vim plugin that updates existing tag files on save.

I've been using it for years without problems, with the exception that it enforces a maximum size on the tags files. Unless you have a *really* large set of code all indexed in the same tags file, you shouldn't hit that limit, though.

Note that Auto Tag requires Python support in vim.

Comment: I tried it but after saving the file it still does not work. How do I find out that I have a build with Python support?

Comment: @xralf on Vim use `:ve`. If `+python` or `+python/dyn' is there, then you have Python in your build.

Comment: Python is there. I sourced the file from `.vimrc` with `:so autotag.vim` but updating does not work.

Comment: It updates existing tags, so you need to do the first tag generation manually. I've edited my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: OK, I will do it as you write. They closed this question, please move the answer to the original duplicate and I will delete this. Thank you.