# VIM Autocreating CTags

Tags: vim, ctags

I love Ctags but the fact that every time I add a new method I need to recreate my file it can be counter productive, not only that but if I need to restart my VIM session it is even worse, also I have noticed that I need to create a CTags file for every directory I want to work with rather than just making one in the root folder and having all the folders having access to it.

Any tips and recommendations?

Comment: You may have looked already, but here is an existing question about automating ctags in vim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155449/vim-auto-generate-ctags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already wrote a plugin to do exactly what you need: [Indexer](http://goo.gl/pT0E9).

It provides painless automatic tags generation for the whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. You can use it independently or as an add-on for another plugin [project.tar.gz](http://goo.gl/Dwkc3).

In the first way, you can declare your projects in `~/.indexer_files` like this:

```
[CoolProject]

/home/user/cool_project

[AnotherProject]
option:ctags_params = "--languages=c++"

/home/user/another_project/src
/home/user/another_project/lib
```

And then, when you open any file from `/home/user/cool_project` , all this project will be indexed by ctags. Tags is generated in background, so, you do not have to wait while ctags generates tags. When you open tags from another project, tags is generated for it too. Tags from different projects is never mixed. When you save file from project, tags is silently updated. You do not have to care about it, it just works.

For detailed information, see my article: [Vim: convenient code navigation for your projects](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation), which explains the usage of Indexer + Vimprj thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I def will try it out. Could you elaborate on "Projects"? When you talk about projects you are just talking about a folder where I will be doing development. Also, can the wild card be used instead of defining each file type? * . * rather than * . c, * . h...

Comment: Yes, i mean "Project" is just a directory with your source files. (or maybe several different directories).

Answer (score 2):

With this in your `.vimrc`

```
set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME
```

Vim will look for a `tags` file in the directory of the current file first, then in the current directory, then up and up until it reaches `$HOME`.

Automatic `tags` generation can be done with a plugin like [AutoTag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1343) or with a one liner in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.js silent! !jsctags . &
```

Comment: You can also put your tags file under another directory.  In my place of employ we put a lot of autogenerated things in a directory called _local in each project's root; `set tags=_local/tags;/` works great for me (even if it searches above the project directory it's looking for a folder named _local which it won't find).  Mind I also have vim always `lcd` to the current buffer's directory on BufEnter...

Comment: @dash-tom-bang you should try `set autochdir`.

Comment: I would have used `autochdir` if it had worked properly.  :)  I don't remember the specifics but it didn't when I started using vim a few years ago.  (A google search indicates that some bugs relating to it have been fixed in a recent 7.3 build but my solution has worked reliably.  See also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file)

Comment: I've started using Vim 2 years ago and `autochdir` never failed me.

Comment: I have now remembered that it caused failures in :vimgrep when searching wildcarded directory hierarchies that weren't rooted.  E.g. `:vimgrep /term/ **/*.txt`; it would switch directories during the search and only end up descending the first directory at each level.