# ctags automatic tag writing

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Thus far I have installed exuberant-ctags from synaptic, and also attained the older version before exuberant: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=610

First of all, do I need both?  I would rather just use exuberant, if possible.

Furthermore, I am  attempting to utilize the following script to auto-generate tags (which isn't working): 
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Autocmd_to_update_ctags_file

I checked out the post at : [Vim auto-generate ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155449/vim-auto-generate-ctags)
and alot of people use easytags (which I made a post about since I could not get it to work).

Any suggestions for auto writing of tags?

Thank you

Comment: Effortless Ctags with Git: http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html

Answer (score 0):

The first plugin in your question is not the old ctags that was deprecated by exuberant ctags: it's just one of the many vim plugins written to interact with ctags. And it does the generation too.

Technically, you don't need any plugin to make vim work with ctags, `:help tags` and `:help ctags` have a lot of useful info, read them.

There are many other tag generation plugins (some are listed in the answers to the question you linked to): try them all and make your decision based on your experience/needs.

In the future, try to make your questions clearer and more focused (what did you try, what worked, what files...).